# How to get monthly data from three separate table

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have three separate tables which stores data.

**Table1 (executes and stores weekly. use data from last week (e.g. 4/27 to 5/3))**:

```
Date         Value1     Value2
5/3/2014      56          13
5/10/2014     12          25
5/17/2014     90          52
5/24/2014     82          36
5/31/2014     76          98
6/7/2014      34          25
6/14/2014     13          63
6/21/2014     45          98
...
```

**Table2 (executes and stores weekly. use data from last week (e.g. 4/27 to 5/3))**:

```
Date         Value3      Value4
5/3/2014       54          62
5/10/2014      43          36
5/17/2014      90          43
5/24/2014      54          35
5/31/2014      76          45
6/7/2014       34          43
6/14/2014      23          37
6/21/2014      34          56
...
```

**Table3 (executes and stores daily from 4/27 and so forth)**:

```
Date         Value5      Value6
4/27/2014      56          45
4/28/2014      34          34
4/29/2014      23          34
4/30/2014      15          90
5/1/2014       34          23
5/2/2014       45          12
5/3/2014       46          35
5/4/2014       67          38
5/5/2014       34          23
...
```

How can I write a query which will calculate each column by MONTH?

My table will look like this:

```
Month     Value1     Value2     Value3     Value4     Value5     Value6
April      NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       128         203
May        316        224        317        221        226         131
```

I have the query which gets the first of the current month:

```
CAST(DATEADD(d, - DATEPART(d, @DATE) + 1, @DATE) as DATE)
```

First of the next month:

```
CAST(DATEADD(d, - DATEPART(d, @DATE) + 1, DATEADD(m, 1, @DATE)) as DATE)
```

I am thinking my query can be something like this:

```
SELECT
     DATENAME(MONTH, @DATE) as [Date],
     (SELECT [Value1] From [database].[dbo].[Table1]
          WHERE [Date] >= CAST(DATEADD(d, - DATEPART(d, @DATE) + 1, @DATE) as DATE)
          AND [Date] < CAST(DATEADD(d, - DATEPART(d, @DATE) + 1, DATEADD(m, 1, @DATE)) as DATE)
     ) AS [VAL1],
     (SELECT [Value2] From [database].[dbo].[Table1]
          WHERE [Date] >= CAST(DATEADD(d, - DATEPART(d, @DATE) + 1, @DATE) as DATE)
          AND [Date] < CAST(DATEADD(d, - DATEPART(d, @DATE) + 1, DATEADD(m, 1, @DATE)) as DATE)
     ) AS [VAL2],
     (SELECT [Value3] From [database].[dbo].[Table2]
          WHERE [Date] >= CAST(DATEADD(d, - DATEPART(d, @DATE) + 1, @DATE) as DATE)
          AND [Date] < CAST(DATEADD(d, - DATEPART(d, @DATE) + 1, DATEADD(m, 1, @DATE)) as DATE)
     ) AS [VAL3],
     (SELECT [Value4] From [database].[dbo].[Table2]
          WHERE [Date] >= CAST(DATEADD(d, - DATEPART(d, @DATE) + 1, @DATE) as DATE)
          AND [Date] < CAST(DATEADD(d, - DATEPART(d, @DATE) + 1, DATEADD(m, 1, @DATE)) as DATE)
     ) AS [VAL4],
     HOW TO DO VALUE5,
     HOW TO DO VALUE6
     INTO [database].[dbo].[tablemonthly]
```

I am requesting some help in completing the above query.

Also, how can I use an `IIF` statement with the above query so it only adds the row once and update only Value5 and Value6 as it is DAILY and keep the other intact because it will be part of a bigger Stored Procedure which is ran daily?

My Three tables is:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure you get all the months you need to have a reference table -- here I use a CTE but you could just make the table.  You could also use a recursive CTE to build the table based on input instead of hard coding the values as I did here.

Note I'm using the technique that Gordon mentioned to join all the data together in a union.

```
WITH Ranges AS
(
   SELECT 'April' AS M, '4/1/2014' AS [START], '4/30/2014' AS [END]
  UNION ALL
   SELECT 'May', '5/1/2014', '5/31/2014'
-- etc
), Data AS
(
   select [date], value1, value2, NULL as value3, NULL as value4, NULL as value5, NULL as value6 from table1
 union all
   select [date], NULL, NULL, value3, value4, NULL, NULL from table2
 union all
   select [date], NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, value5, value6 from table3
)
, Joined AS
(
   SELECT M as [Month], Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4, Value5, Value6
   FROM Ranges R
   JOIN Data D ON D.[DATE] >= R.[START] AND D.[Date] <= R.[END]
)
SELECT [Month], SUM(Value1), SUM(Value2), SUM(Value3), SUM(Value4), SUM(Value5), SUM(Value6)
FROM Joined
GROUP BY [Month]
```

Comment: Does this take into account that, Value5 and Value6 are daily and adds based on the month?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge - I think so.

Comment: For the month of MAY My VALUE1 column adds up to 170 but after I run the query, it gives me 3400 and all the other values are wrong as well for May.

Comment: That only gives me one month only.

Comment: I will update my question with the table I created so you have a better idea :)

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge - try the new query

Comment: Hogan, I think you may have did it buddy!!! I am going to test a few more time and update you :) THANKS THANKS THANKS!!!

Comment: One quick question, if I run it every day and I only want to update VALUE5 and VALUE6 because it is updated daily, how do I achieve that?

Comment: Lets say I run the code again it will enter the three row below the previous three rows because there is no condition checking. How can I use an `IF EXISTS` code above the `SELECT` code to ensure if the month already exists in the table, do not add the row again... makes sense?

Comment: Probably you want to use update but not insert... however this is a new question... please create a new question on SO.  Answering this question did not mean I signed up to be a personal consultant.

Comment: Ahhhh Sorry... Didn't mean it that way :). Thanks. I will create a new question.

Comment: Hey Hogan, Please help me one more time. I asked my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23409446/why-columns-are-invalid-in-my-query. I am trying the same query with a real table but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

This query lists the YEAR, MONTH, and totals for VALUE#s.

Even though the query may be long, it would run very quickly, because the joins operate on a smaller subset of Table1, Table2, and Table3 (because they are first filtered). Then, they are joined using the Month and Year parts of the Date column. Finally, the data is ordered by Month and Year.

```
SELECT
COALESCE(DATENAME(YEAR, Table1.[Date]), DATENAME(YEAR, Table2.[Date]), DATENAME(YEAR, Table3.[Date])) AS Year
, COALESCE(DATENAME(MONTH, Table1.[Date]), DATENAME(MONTH, Table2.[Date]), DATENAME(MONTH, Table3.[Date])) AS Month 
, COALESCE(SUM(Table1.Value1), 0) Value1 
, COALESCE(SUM(Table1.Value2), 0) Value2 
, COALESCE(SUM(Table2.Value3), 0) Value3 
, COALESCE(SUM(Table2.Value4), 0) Value4 
, COALESCE(SUM(Table3.Value5), 0) Value5 
, COALESCE(SUM(Table3.Value6), 0) Value6 
FROM
(
  SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE [Date] >= CAST(DATEADD(d, - DATEPART(d, @DATE) + 1, @DATE) as DATE)
AND [Date] < CAST(DATEADD(d, - DATEPART(d, @DATE) + 1, DATEADD(m, 9, @DATE)) as DATE)
) Table1
FULL JOIN
(
  SELECT *
FROM Table2
WHERE [Date] >= CAST(DATEADD(d, - DATEPART(d, @DATE) + 1, @DATE) as DATE)
AND [Date] < CAST(DATEADD(d, - DATEPART(d, @DATE) + 1, DATEADD(m, 9, @DATE)) as DATE)
) Table2
ON DATENAME(MONTH, Table1.[Date]) = DATENAME(MONTH, Table2.[Date])
AND DATENAME(YEAR, Table1.[Date]) = DATENAME(YEAR, Table2.[Date])
FULL JOIN
(
  SELECT *
FROM Table3
WHERE [Date] >= CAST(DATEADD(d, - DATEPART(d, @DATE) + 1, @DATE) as DATE)
AND [Date] < CAST(DATEADD(d, - DATEPART(d, @DATE) + 1, DATEADD(m, 9, @DATE)) as DATE)
) Table3
ON DATENAME(MONTH, Table1.[Date]) = DATENAME(MONTH, Table3.[Date])
AND DATENAME(YEAR, Table1.[Date]) = DATENAME(YEAR, Table3.[Date])
GROUP BY 
COALESCE(DATENAME(YEAR, Table1.[Date]), DATENAME(YEAR, Table2.[Date]), DATENAME(YEAR, Table3.[Date]))
, COALESCE(DATENAME(MONTH, Table1.[Date]), DATENAME(MONTH, Table2.[Date]), DATENAME(MONTH, Table3.[Date]))
ORDER BY 
COALESCE(DATENAME(YEAR, Table1.[Date]), DATENAME(YEAR, Table2.[Date]), DATENAME(YEAR, Table3.[Date]))
, MONTH(CAST(COALESCE(DATENAME(MONTH, Table1.[Date]), DATENAME(MONTH, Table2.[Date]), DATENAME(MONTH, Table3.[Date])) + ' 1 2014' AS DATETIME));
```

Here is the updated <kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d27ac/1)</kbd>, which contains data for all sorts of combinations.

Comment: What if there is a month that is not in Table1 -- this will fail.

Comment: @Hogan Agreed. I will re-write the query.

Comment: Is the query rewritten so i can test? Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you. Not rushing you, just curious so I can test it out :)

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge I have rewritten the query. Please test it when you get a chance :-)

Comment: Thank you for the query but it is only showing me for one month only.

Comment: Testing it right now for multiple months. Please stand by.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge It does work for multiple months. Please see this example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2cc70/14

Comment: This fiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2cc70/15) uses the exact same syntax. Simply replace '2014-05-01' with @DATE and .dt with .date (since I changed the column name).

Comment: Testing... Stand By :). BTW I Upvoted because you took your time to help me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51776/discussion-between-joseph-b-and-searchforknowledge)

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do this by by union'ing the tables together and then extracting what you want:

```
select datename(month, @date) as [date],
       max(value1) as value1, max(value2) as value2,
       max(value3) as value3, max(value4) as value4,
       sum(value5) as value5, sum(value6) as value6
into [database].[dbo].[tablemonthly]
from ((select [date], value1, value2, NULL as value3, NULL as value4, NULL as value5, NULL as value6
       from table1
      ) union all
      (select [date], NULL, NULL, value3, value4, NULL, NULL
       from table2
      ) union all
      (select [date], NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, value5, value6
       from table3
      )
     ) t
where [Date] >= CAST(DATEADD(d, - DATEPART(d, @DATE) + 1, @DATE) as DATE) and
      [Date] < CAST(DATEADD(d, - DATEPART(d, @DATE) + 1, DATEADD(m, 1, @DATE)) as DATE);
```

You can do multiple months at the same time by using `group by`.

EDIT:

The query for getting multiple months is:

```
select year([date]) as yr, month([date]) as mon,
       max(value1) as value1, max(value2) as value2,
       max(value3) as value3, max(value4) as value4,
       sum(value5) as value5, sum(value6) as value6
into [database].[dbo].[tablemonthly]
from ((select [date], value1, value2, NULL as value3, NULL as value4, NULL as value5, NULL as value6
       from table1
      ) union all
      (select [date], NULL, NULL, value3, value4, NULL, NULL
       from table2
      ) union all
      (select [date], NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, value5, value6
       from table3
      )
     ) t
group by year([date]), month([date])
```

(I also put the year in to avoid ambiguity.)

This replaces the `where` with a `group by` with the associated changes to the `select`.

Comment: Does this take into account that, Value5 and Value6 are daily and adds based on the month?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge . . . I think so, now that I switched to using `sum()` for those values rather than `max()`.  The `where` should identify the right range and the `sum()` should add them together.

Comment: [strike]I get a `Incorrect Syntax near ')'` error when I run the query[/strike] I fixed the query.

Comment: Works great, except the table also has data for MAY and JUNE which is not being shown here...

Comment: Something went wrong there... For  Value1 -> Value4 it only shows the last entry while for Value5 and Value6 it does the calculation correctly...

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge . . . Change the `max()` to `sum()` in those cases.  Your original query suggested that there was only one value, but if there are more, then you might want to sum them up.

Comment: Ok I am testing it out. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
with MonthDataSummed(theMonth,value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6) as 
(
    select dateName(Month,date),Sum(value1),Sum(value2),null,null,null,null from table11
     group by dateName(Month,date)
     UNION all
     select dateName(Month,date),NULL,NULL,Sum(value3),Sum(value4),null,null 
     from table22
     group by dateName(Month,date)
     UNION all
     select dateName(Month,date),NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Sum(value5),Sum(value6) 
     from table33
     group by dateName(Month,date)
 )
,SummedFlattened(theMonth,value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6) as 
(
    select
    theMonth,Max(value1),Max(value2),Max(value3),Max(value4),Max(value5),Max(value6)
    from MonthDataSummed
    group by theMonth
)
SELECT * FROM SummedFlattened
```

Comment: It is not adding it correctly... Only gets the last entry and shows that in the final table. Not adding each occurrence.

Comment: which value is wrong? I have used my own test data.

Comment: I think I was able to make some changes and might have gotten it to work :)

Comment: ok great but which result value was incorrect when you run my query against your data?

Comment: Ok, think I see it. Should be dateName(Month,date) instead of date in the group by. Agree?

Comment: Think you are right. Let me test it out. Thank you btw. I UPVOTED... So Far :)