# Why columns are invalid in my query

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have the following query which gets the total for each month taking data from three different tables:

```
--DROP TABLE [database].[dbo].[finaltable]
--TRUNCATE TABLE [database].[dbo].[finaltable]
;WITH
Ranges AS (
    SELECT 'January' AS M, '1/1/2014' AS [START], '1/31/2014' AS [END]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'February', '2/1/2014', '2/28/2014'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'March', '3/1/2014', '3/31/2014'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'April', '4/1/2014', '4/30/2014'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'May', '5/1/2014', '5/31/2014'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'June', '6/1/2014', '6/30/2014'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'July', '7/1/2014', '7/31/2014'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'August', '8/1/2014', '8/31/2014'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'September', '9/1/2014', '9/30/2014'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'October', '10/1/2014', '10/31/2014'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'November', '11/1/2014', '11/30/2014'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'December', '12/1/2014', '12/31/2014'
),
Data AS (
    SELECT [Date], [APSURGICALTOTAL], [APDERMTOTAL], [GYNNONGYNTOTAL], [CYTOHPV], [INHOUSE], [HEMOTOLOGY], [CHEMISTRY], [BLOODBANK], [REFLAB], [URINALYSIS], [SEROLOGY], [MICROBIOLOGY]
    FROM [database].[dbo].[weeklytable]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [Date], 101), [LastWeekEMROrders], [LastWeekAccLabOrders], [LastWeekLabResults], NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
    FROM [database].[dbo].[dailytable]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [Date], 101), [RAD EMR ORDERS], [EMR ORDERS], [ACCESSIONED LAB ORDERS], [RAD RESULTED], [LAB_RESULT], [RAD ACCESSIONED], [PENDING FOR PROCESSING], NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
    FROM [database].[dbo].[othertable]
),
Joined AS (
    SELECT M AS [Month],
    [APSURGICALTOTAL],
    [APDERMTOTAL],
    [GYNNONGYNTOTAL],
    [CYTOHPV],
    [INHOUSE],
    [HEMOTOLOGY],
    [CHEMISTRY],
    [BLOODBANK],
    [REFLAB],
    [URINALYSIS],
    [SEROLOGY],
    [MICROBIOLOGY],
    [LastWeekEMROrders],
    [LastWeekAccLabOrders],
    [LastWeekLabResults],
    [RAD EMR ORDERS],
    [EMR ORDERS],
    [ACCESSIONED LAB ORDERS],
    [RAD RESULTED],
    [LAB_RESULT],
    [RAD ACCESSIONED],
    [PENDING FOR PROCESSING]
    FROM Ranges R
    JOIN Data D ON D.[DATE] >= R.[START] AND D.[Date] <= R.[END]
)

SELECT [Month],
    SUM([APSURGICALTOTAL]) AS [SURGTOTAL],
    SUM([APDERMTOTAL]) AS [DERMTOTAL],
    SUM(GYNNONGYNTOTAL) AS [GNGTOTAL],
    SUM(CYTOHPV) AS [HPVTOTAL],
    SUM(INHOUSE) AS [HOUSETOTAL],
    SUM([HEMOTOLOGY]) AS [HEMOTOTAL],
    SUM([CHEMISTRY]) AS [CHEMTOTAL],
    SUM([BLOODBANK]) AS [BBTOTAL],
    SUM([REFLAB]) AS [REFTOTAL],
    SUM([URINALYSIS]) AS [URINTOTAL],
    SUM([SEROLOGY]) AS [SEROTOTAL],
    SUM([MICROBIOLOGY]) AS [MICROTOTAL],
    SUM([LastWeekEMROrders]) AS [LWEMRORDERSTOTAL],
    SUM([LastWeekAccLabOrders]) AS [LWACCLABORDERSTOTAL],
    SUM([LastWeekLabResults]) AS [LWLABRESULTSTOTAL],
    SUM([RAD EMR ORDERS]) AS [RADEMRTOTAL],
    SUM([EMR ORDERS]) AS [EMRORDERTOTAL],
    SUM([ACCESSIONED LAB ORDERS]) AS [ACCLABORDERSTOTAL],
    SUM([RAD RESULTED]) AS [RADRESTOTAL],
    SUM([LAB_RESULT]) AS [LABREDTOTAL],
    SUM([RAD ACCESSIONED]) AS [RADACCTOTAL],
    SUM([PENDING FOR PROCESSING]) AS [PENFORPROCTOTAL],
    month([Month]+'1 2010') AS [MonthNum]
INTO [database].[dbo].[finaltable]
FROM Joined
GROUP BY [Month]
```

I get the following errors:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 56
Invalid column name 'LastWeekEMROrders'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 57
Invalid column name 'LastWeekAccLabOrders'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 58
Invalid column name 'LastWeekLabResults'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 59
Invalid column name 'RAD EMR ORDERS'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 60
Invalid column name 'EMR ORDERS'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 61
Invalid column name 'ACCESSIONED LAB ORDERS'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 62
Invalid column name 'RAD RESULTED'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 63
Invalid column name 'LAB_RESULT'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 64
Invalid column name 'RAD ACCESSIONED'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 65
Invalid column name 'PENDING FOR PROCESSING'.
```

I asked my original question here with dummy table: [Stackoverflow Question Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23394656/how-to-get-monthly-data-from-three-separate-table)

A lot of people helped me with the dummy tables. Now I am trying to do the same with my real table but it's giving me all the errors listed above.

How can I resolve the error, so it works just like it was working with the dummy tables?

Comment: The way that you're constructing your `Data` CTE looks nothing like in the answer to your other question. There, the first query in the union named **all** of the columns and used `NULL`s for columns that weren't in that table. Then the second query fitted itself to the same sets of columns as the first query, putting its columns in the right place given the names given by the first query, and `NULL`s everywhere else, etc.

Comment: You understand that select into only works once right? If this is aone time load to the table that is fine to use, but if you expect to insert other records again, you will need to use an insert statement.

Comment: Yep. I already modified it once I ran it one time. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the columns "line up" in the UNION ALL statement.  It is easier to see if you put the column names in for all columns -- like this:

**You need to make sure your date column is a date or datetime type.  If you store strings then convert them -- trying to do a date compare on a string is a bad plan -- use the dates and let the server compare apples to apples.**

```
Data AS (
    SELECT 
      CAST([Date] AS DateTime) AS [DATE],
      [APSURGICALTOTAL],
      [APDERMTOTAL],
      [GYNNONGYNTOTAL],
      [CYTOHPV],
      [INHOUSE],
      [HEMOTOLOGY],
      [CHEMISTRY],
      [BLOODBANK],
      [REFLAB],
      [URINALYSIS],
      [SEROLOGY],
      [MICROBIOLOGY],
      NULL AS [LastWeekEMROrders],
      NULL AS [LastWeekAccLabOrders],
      NULL AS [LastWeekLabResults],
      NULL AS [RAD EMR ORDERS],
      NULL AS [EMR ORDERS],
      NULL AS [ACCESSIONED LAB ORDERS],
      NULL AS [RAD RESULTED],
      NULL AS [LAB_RESULT],
      NULL AS [RAD ACCESSIONED],
      NULL AS [PENDING FOR PROCESSING]
    FROM [database].[dbo].[weeklytable]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
      [Date],
      NULL AS [APSURGICALTOTAL],
      NULL AS [APDERMTOTAL],
      NULL AS [GYNNONGYNTOTAL],
      NULL AS [CYTOHPV],
      NULL AS [INHOUSE],
      NULL AS [HEMOTOLOGY],
      NULL AS [CHEMISTRY],
      NULL AS [BLOODBANK],
      NULL AS [REFLAB],
      NULL AS [URINALYSIS],
      NULL AS [SEROLOGY],
      NULL AS [MICROBIOLOGY],
      [LastWeekEMROrders],
      [LastWeekAccLabOrders],
      [LastWeekLabResults],
      NULL AS [RAD EMR ORDERS],
      NULL AS [EMR ORDERS],
      NULL AS [ACCESSIONED LAB ORDERS],
      NULL AS [RAD RESULTED],
      NULL AS [LAB_RESULT],
      NULL AS [RAD ACCESSIONED],
      NULL AS [PENDING FOR PROCESSING]
    FROM [database].[dbo].[dailytable]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      [Date],
      NULL AS [APSURGICALTOTAL],
      NULL AS [APDERMTOTAL],
      NULL AS [GYNNONGYNTOTAL],
      NULL AS [CYTOHPV],
      NULL AS [INHOUSE],
      NULL AS [HEMOTOLOGY],
      NULL AS [CHEMISTRY],
      NULL AS [BLOODBANK],
      NULL AS [REFLAB],
      NULL AS [URINALYSIS],
      NULL AS [SEROLOGY],
      NULL AS [MICROBIOLOGY],
      NULL AS [LastWeekEMROrders],
      NULL AS [LastWeekAccLabOrders],
      NULL AS [LastWeekLabResults],
      [RAD EMR ORDERS],
      [EMR ORDERS],
      [ACCESSIONED LAB ORDERS],
      [RAD RESULTED],
      [LAB_RESULT],
      [RAD ACCESSIONED],
      [PENDING FOR PROCESSING]
    FROM [database].[dbo].[othertable]
),
```

Comment: The `weeklytable` has a row with the date `4/26/2014`. The `dailytable` has a row with the date `2014-04-26 00:00:00.00`. The `othertable` has a row has a row with the date '2014-05-01` but when I run the query, nothing is added to the `finaltable`. Please help...

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge - Can you write me a recommendation?

Comment: HA HA HA... I sure can! When would you like it?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with this portion:

```
SELECT [Date], [APSURGICALTOTAL], [APDERMTOTAL], [GYNNONGYNTOTAL], [CYTOHPV], [INHOUSE], [HEMOTOLOGY], [CHEMISTRY], [BLOODBANK], [REFLAB], [URINALYSIS], [SEROLOGY], [MICROBIOLOGY]
    FROM [database].[dbo].[weeklytable]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [Date], 101), [LastWeekEMROrders], [LastWeekAccLabOrders], [LastWeekLabResults], NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
    FROM [database].[dbo].[dailytable]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [Date], 101), [RAD EMR ORDERS], [EMR ORDERS], [ACCESSIONED LAB ORDERS], [RAD RESULTED], [LAB_RESULT], [RAD ACCESSIONED], [PENDING FOR PROCESSING], NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
    FROM [database].[dbo].[othertable]
```

The problem columns do not appear in the original select.  When you UNION ALL, the columns for the first select should match the following queries.

Comment: Exactly this. Even though the highlighted line is probably the outer `select`, the failing statement is inside a `with`.